# loading the paypal website in the webview

Tags: iphone, paypal

I am developing one application, it contains purchasing of products. I am loading the paypal website in the webview when user is clicking the buy button.

But i read the apple guidelines "Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected".

I will explain the flow: 
Case 1: I have a product details page and there is a buy option in that page. By clicking that button i am navigating to that product's website payment section and all payment will be from that site.

Case 2: I have the option to send cash to another person, so that while clicking that option i am navigating the user to the paypal's website.

Now i am totally confused. Can i proceed like this? Will my app get rejected? Please give me solution to sort this out?

Comment: It depends. What would the user be purchasing?

Comment: Check out [this thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110967/ios-credit-card-paypal-transaction-not-via-in-app-purcahses

Comment: I have edited my question...added two cases in my application...kindly go through that....i think that apple guide lines again updated recently...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question is what are the people buying?

If it's a physical product then any method will be fine.

If it's a digital product then then you will have to use Apple' in-app purchase.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between Physical product and digital product?

Comment: Thanks ade..in my case it is physical product. Some times user will be sending cash to his friend. In case of physical product is this not valid:"Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, such as a “buy” button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected"

Comment: @VineethG:I  think digital books, magazines, photos, artwork, game levels, game characters are digital products and products like television, computer etc are called Physical products.

Comment: "to be used in the app" is the key phrase - if it's a physical product it can't be "used in the app".

Comment: If i am purchasing a ticket, then is it possible?After purchasing, a ticket will be generated and i can show that ticket from app for the entrance......What about this situation...?Kindly explain..

Comment: In that case "11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected" means that you can't use IAP for ticket purchase if you wanted to. The ticket purchase you describe is for goods or a service used outside of the application.